# Is "filling someone's bucket" an idiomatic expression?

Tags: expressions, idioms

According to a passage on [prezi.com](https://prezi.com/1aevab8phj8u/what-does-it-mean-to-fill-a-bucket/#:%7E:text=Filling%20somebody%27s%20bucket%20means%20that,his%20or%20her%20day%20better.),

> "Filling somebody's bucket means that you do or say something to that
> person that makes his or her day better."

But I couldn't find this expression in any dictionary. I wonder if it really is an idiomatic expression.

Also, according to another [website](https://www.embracingourdifferences.org/volunteer-bucketfiller#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CBucket%20fillers%22%20are%20defined%20as,spread%20good%20feelings%20to%20others.):

> "Bucket fillers are defined as individuals who without being asked,
> help give compliments and spread good feelings to others."

Comment: It is not, it’s this guy’s personal metaphor or mantra. He’s selling the phrase and concept as his way of promoting compassion.

Comment: @DanBron - But there are examples from other websites as well.

Comment: Bucket filling/fillers seems to be an infantile and patronising phrase whose cloying and fulsome intent is transparent to all. I suggest that, within a few years at the most, the phrase will be, mercifully, forgotten. I suggest that you become aware of the phrase and its meaning but that you do not use it.

Comment: I *think* I've heard the expression (or something fairly similar) with the meaning you gave, but in my opinion it's way too obscure to be considered idiomatic. I don't think I've heard the term "bucket fillers".